# What is the ruby equivalent of a c++ using declaration?

Tags: c++, ruby, using

I understand that you can accomplish namespacing in Ruby using modules.

However, sufficiently lengthy namespaces can make code very un-readable.
in C++ this is solved with the [using declaration](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fusing_declaration_class_members.htm)

What is the ruby equivalent of a c++ using declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `include`.

```
include Some::Lengthy::Module::NameSpace
```